# Fourier transform of $1/(1+ |x|^{1/2})$

Tags: fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

This function is between the function $f_1 = 1$ and $f_2 = 1/(1+ x^2)$. For the former, the Fourier transform is a delta function (a distribution, or a generalized function). For the latter, the Fourier transform is something like $a e^{-b|k|}$. I thus expect something between a delta function and a regular function.

What is it exactly? Is it in the form of $a \delta(k) + b(k)$, where $a$ is some constant and $b$ some regular function?

Comment: If you evaluate the FT as an improper integral, you'll get a locally integrable function $F$ which is $\Theta(|\omega|^{-1/2})$ at zero and $\Theta(|\omega|^{-3/2})$ at infinity. The regular functional induced by $F$ will be the distributional transform. $F$ has a closed form in terms of the Meijer G-function.